# Sort by number of matches without Match Against

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not want to use Match Against because if I have many keywords in a row do not get the relevance that I want to make an inquiry. The goal is to get the order by the number of matches.

These are the details MySQL database that currently use for testing:

```
-- 
-- Base de datos: `libros`
-- 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `libros`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `libros` (
  `id_unico` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text NOT NULL,
  `id_libro` text NOT NULL,
  `tipo` text NOT NULL,
  `posicion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` float(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `proveedor` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_unico`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 
-- Volcar la base de datos para la tabla `libros`
-- 

INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (1, 'La ladrona de los libros', '9788426419866', 'nuevo', 200, 10.00, 'Ladrona, Libros, Ladron', 'eBay');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (2, 'Los surcos del azar', '9788415685364', 'nuevo', 3, 13.00, 'Surcos, Azar', 'Marcelo');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (3, 'Los surcos del azar', '9788415685364', 'nuevo', 5, 15.00, 'Surcos, Azar', 'Amazon');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (4, 'El castillo', '9788467520170', 'nuevo', 10, 20.00, 'Castillo, Medieval', 'Marcelo');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (5, 'El Castillo', '9788467520170', 'nuevo', 5, 15.00, 'Castillo, Medieval', 'Casa del libro');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (6, 'La jungla de los listos', '9788467040470', 'nuevo', 6, 30.00, 'Jungla, Libros', 'eBay');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (7, 'La jungla de los libros', '9788467040470', 'nuevo', 4, 19.00, 'Jungla, Libros', 'Amazon');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (8, 'La ladrona de los libros', '9788426419866', 'nuevo', 99, 40.00, 'Ladrona, Libros, Ladron, 2014', 'Luis');
INSERT INTO `libros` VALUES (9, 'La ladrona de los libros', '9788426419866', 'nuevo', 21, 22.00, 'Ladrona, Libros, Ladron', 'Lili');
```

The query that I run is:

```
SELECT *, SUM(
IF(keywords LIKE '%Ladrona%', 1, 0) +
IF(keywords LIKE '%Libros%', 1, 0) +
IF(keywords LIKE '%2014%', 1, 0)
) total FROM libros
 WHERE tipo = 'nuevo' GROUP BY id_libro HAVING total > 0 ORDER BY total DESC, posicion ASC, precio DESC
```

I would like to return the id_unico "8" on the first result and can not. Instead returns id_unico 1 and 6 respectively. What should I do?

Comment: why you want get id 8 ?

Comment: The problem is you are grouping by `id_libro` but there are multiple `id_unico` values per `id_libro` value, so the query just returns the first one (1). What are your desired results given that there are multiple column values per `id_libro` value?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use GROUP BY in a SELECT * statement. All columns which are not calculated by an aggregate function (SUM, MAX, etc...) have to be in the GROUP BY.

So maybe what you want is:

```
SELECT id_libro, SUM(
    IF(keywords LIKE '%Ladrona%', 1, 0) +
    IF(keywords LIKE '%Libros%', 1, 0) +
    IF(keywords LIKE '%2014%', 1, 0)
  ) total
  FROM libros
  WHERE tipo = 'nuevo'
  GROUP BY id_libro
  HAVING total>0
  ORDER BY total DESC
```

Only if you are absolutely sure that all records with the same id_libro also have the same posicion and precio, then you can do this:

```
SELECT id_libro, posicion, precio, SUM(
    IF(keywords LIKE '%Ladrona%', 1, 0) +
    IF(keywords LIKE '%Libros%', 1, 0) +
    IF(keywords LIKE '%2014%', 1, 0)
  ) total
  FROM libros
  WHERE tipo = 'nuevo'
  GROUP BY id_libro, posicion, precio
  HAVING total>0
  ORDER BY total DESC, posicion ASC, precio DESC
```

... but this would also mean the db is very badly designed :(

Comment: "All columns which are not calculated by an aggregate function (SUM, MAX, etc...) have to be in the GROUP BY." Actually, in mysql, this is not true...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   SELECT *, (
 IF(keywords LIKE '%Ladrona%', 1, 0) +
 IF(keywords LIKE '%Libros%', 1, 0) +
 IF(keywords LIKE '%2014%', 1, 0)
  ) total FROM libros
 WHERE tipo = 'nuevo'  HAVING total > 0 
 ORDER BY total DESC, posicion ASC, precio DESC
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6af4ef/3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are grouping by `id_libro` but there are multiple `id_unico` values per `id_libro` value, so the query just returns the first one (1). To get a concatenated list of values for each `id_libro` grouping, you can use `group_concat`:

```
SELECT
    group_concat(id_unico) id_unico,
    titulo,
    id_libro,
    tipo,
    group_concat(posicion) posicion,
    group_concat(precio) precio,
    group_concat(keywords) keywords,
    group_concat(proveedor) proveedor,
    SUM(
       IF(keywords LIKE '%Ladrona%', 1, 0) +
       IF(keywords LIKE '%Libros%', 1, 0) +
       IF(keywords LIKE '%2014%', 1, 0)
       ) total
FROM libros
WHERE tipo = 'nuevo'
GROUP BY id_libro
HAVING total > 0
ORDER BY total DESC, posicion ASC, precio DESC
```